# Python connect socket to process

Tags: python, windows, sockets, process

I have a (*very*) simple web server I wrote in C and I want to test it. I wrote it so it takes data on stdin and sends out on stdout. How would I connect the input/output of a socket (created with socket.accept()) to the input/output of a process created with subprocess.Popen?

Sounds simple, right? Here's the killer: I'm running Windows.

Can anyone help?

Here's what I've tried:

1. Passing the client object itself as stdin/out to subprocess.Popen. (It never hurts to try.)
2. Passing socket.makefile() results as stdin/out to subprocess.Popen.
3. Passing the socket's file number to os.fdopen().

Also, in case the question was unclear, here's a slimmed-down version of my code:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('', PORT))
sock.listen(5)
cli, addr = sock.accept()
p = subprocess.Popen([PROG])
#I want to connect 'p' to the 'cli' socket so whatever it sends on stdout
#goes to the client and whatever the client sends goes to its stdin.
#I've tried:
p = subprocess.Popen([PROG], stdin = cli.makefile("r"), stdout = cli.makefile("w"))
p = subprocess.Popen([PROG], stdin = cli, stdout = cli)
p = subprocess.Popen([PROG], stdin = os.fdopen(cli.fileno(), "r"), stdout = os.fdopen(cli.fileno(), "w"))
#but all of them give me either "Bad file descriptor" or "The handle is invalid".
```

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: I had the same issue, but the solution i came up with was to share the socket, writing to the stdin of the process the port of the socket or using the `socket.share` function (in python). I think you should at least consider this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and tried the same way to bind the socket, also on windows. The solution I came out with was to share the socket and bind it on the process to `stdin` and `stdout`. My solutions are completely in python but I guess that they are easily convertible.

```
import socket, subprocess

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(('', PORT))
sock.listen(5)
cli, addr = sock.accept()

process = subprocess.Popen([PROG], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write(cli.share(process.pid))
process.stdin.flush()

# you can now use `cli` as client normally
```

And in the other process:

```
import sys, os, socket

sock = socket.fromshare(os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 372))
sys.stdin = sock.makefile("r")
sys.stdout = sock.makefile("w")

# stdin and stdout now write to `sock`
```

The `372` is the `len` of a measured `socket.share` call. I don't know if this is constant, but it worked for me. This is possible only in windows, as the `share` function is only available on that OS.

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't look like there's a C equivalent of the `share()` and `fromshare()` functions, so I'm not going to accept this because it technically doesn't answer the question. But this is very useful. Thank you.

Comment: It's a windows api call, it has an equivalent but in the windows api, you can read it here: [shared sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740478(v=vs.85).aspx)